# Magento2: General error: 1010 Error dropping database (can't rmdir '.\[project]', errno: 41 "Directory not empty")

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

I'm getting an database issue during Magento uninstallation.

**Here is the error:**

General error: 1010 Error dropping database (can't rmdir '.[project]', errno: 41 "Directory not empty"

**Here is the screenshot:**

[image]

**Note:** I'm using window 11.

Comment: Not sure about this but Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947255/error-in-dropping-a-database-in-mysql-cant-rmdir-oro-errno-41)

Comment: Thanks @AzizKapasi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue has been fixed.**

I had to remove the database directory from the C:\xampp\mysql\data and had to recreate the database in phpmyadmin.

After that, I did setup:install that fixed the issue.

Q: Why I got the same issue?

Ans: Actually, I was getting the MySQL connection issue and to fix the issue, I did some research on the same issue. And as per one of the solution, I copied the xampp\mysql\backup content to xampp\mysql\data directory and replaced the content without taking the data directory backup. This was the primary mistake.

This process corrupted my database tables & to resolve the same issue, I had to remove the database directory from the xampp\mysql\data directory & had to recreate the same database in phpmyadmin.

So basically we just need to find out the MySQL directory into the current system & do the same activity.

**For Example:**

> Xampp: C:\xampp\mysql\data
>
> Wamp:  C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql[active_version]\data

**I hope this helps others if they have the related issue.**